# Google Assistant custom account linkup

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assist-api

I'm trying to link up Google Assistant app with my own server. I used "Implicit" account linking process.

```
Grant Type : Implicit
Client Id : "xxxxxxxx"
Authorization URL : "https://mydomain.login.php"
```

When I launch the app. Displayed card on home screen as "Link testapp to Google". when click on it redirects my home page and authenticated successfully and return back to app page with `accessToken` from my server.

This accessToken added to each request in Google. Till now everything is fine. When I close the session and launch the app again it asks to authentication again. How can I make it implicit authentication only on first time.

Comment: Is this happening only in the simulator, or does it also happen if you test on a mobile device with Assistant or a speaker with Assistant?

Comment: @Prisoner I tested in simulator

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat intended behavior during testing. Since there is no way to reset the user information while you're testing (the action isn't available in the directory), it doesn't use a persistent user id or other user information.